# How to access a stored procedure on another database in DB2

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

From a stored procedure in DB2, how can I access another stored procedure that is located on a different host?

Answer (score 0):

this requires Federation.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.db.fed.overview.doc/topics/cfpint01.html

Comment: Federation only works to access "data" from differenty kind of sources, but this question is about Stored Procedures. Thus, Federation is not the solution.

Comment: @AngocA Not so. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.fed.sysconfig.doc/topics/iiyfafsp04.html

Answer (score -1):

I have never done this, but what about if you create a stored procedure in Java in the source database, and via this stored procedure you call the target database. However, I am not sure if a stored procedure permits to establish another connection via JDBC.

I do not see any possibility to do this via SQL PL, because this kind of stored procedures uses the existing connection, and there is not any option or command to establish a new one.

If you are writing the stored procedure in C/C++, the case is the same as Java.

**Another option:**

You could call the stored procedure in the target database via a trigger, for example after an insert in a specific table for this purpose. Then, you could use federation to see that table in the source database, and you pass the parameters via the insert. When the target database receives the parameters, it will execute the stored procedure.

I do not know if call a stored procedure is possible from a trigger in DB2, and the result cannot be any cursor, just simple values.

Comment: It seems that you can call a stored procedure from a trigger in db2 9.7: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/t0011377.html